# Hotel booking sites with a calendar view, similar to flight search engines?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, hotels, accommodation-search-engines

I was a great fan of [Wotif.com](http://www.wotif.com)'s calendar view, where you could punch a place and a start date and it would show you prices and availability for *all* hotels, which you could then filter down by your criteria.

Alas, Wotif were purchased by Expedia in 2014, and the new owners have apparently proceeded to [gut the site](http://www.feefo.com/AU/en/reviews/Wotif-Australia_WotifAU/?id=1269634&servicefeedbackid=61089925) and [move it wholesale onto Expedia's engine](http://www.smh.com.au/business/wotif-boss-and-other-staff-get-a-permanent-vacation-following-expedia-takeover-20150125-12xrbu.html), which like the vast majority of booking sites out there insists on a specific check-in and check-out date before it will show you any prices.  Boo.

So, **where I can compare prices for lots of hotels for several weeks at once**?

Specific scenario that a winning answer will need to cover: I'd like to see how prices change in Dubbo, NSW, Australia, on weekends and weekdays, before and after local school holidays start on September 21, 2015.

Comment: Edited the title a bit, hope you don't mind. Adding a bounty as well :)

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this is what you would be looking for exactly but I did find on Googles hotel search that you can put in a start date and end date and search. When on the search results page you can click on the little bar chart on the right hand side of the dates and give you a little chart of when it's the cheapest. Google flights is similar as well.[image]

Comment: Good find otherwise, but Google appears to have next to no price data available for hotels in Dubbo: https://www.google.com/hotels/#search;l=Dubbo,+New+South+Wales,+Australia;d=2015-09-13;n=2;usd=1;si=148ea4aa;av=r

Comment: Opps, didn't notice that! Hopefully it will be helpful for other locations.

Comment: Wait this doesn't even work anymore, Google seems to have killed it

Comment: @blackbird57 Hotels are now integrated into Google Search itself.

Comment: @jpatokal the price bar seems to be gone :(

Answer (score 5):

This is only a partial answer, taken from [my answer to another question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/65594/32134). In particular it **is only practical for a limited number of hotels, limited number of days and not always precise**.

[Hostelworld](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/65594/32134) has a price breakdown that we can use with a few drawbacks.

If you can find the hotel/hostel/spot under the bridge that you want to go to on the website, you can specify a travel period ("stay") of up to 15 days. Then pick your place and go to where the price is displayed. You will find the option "View price breakdown" give you the price per night:

[image: Dubbo Ibis]

I took the freedom to fast-forward to 2016 when [school holidays start Saturday 24 September](http://www.nswschoolholiday.com.au/index.php/nsw-school-holiday-dates-2016). Hostelworld has one property for Dubbo, an [Ibis](http://www.accorhotels.com/gb/hotel-3496-ibis-budget-dubbo/index.shtml). I honestly don't see an effect due to the school holidays there, prices go somewhat up the Tuesday before.
I double-checked with the hotel website on three of those days and interestingly I always get the same price displayed, i.e. the above method may not always be useful.

And here are some more catches:

1. You have to find the place you are looking for on the site. Hostelworld does have a decent selection of hotels, but you will not find a Grand Hyatt, apologies.
2. If you are looking at prices over long periods, you have to do a ton of searches due to the max 15 days stay limit.
3. Your desired hotel/room type may not be available on one of the days in the 15 days and not be displayed.
4. Some hotels may have a shorter maximum stay and not enter that list (even though I found them displayed).
5. A different rate may apply for your actual duration of stay than for the 15 days search period and the hotel might have a minimum duration of stay.