# Do Las Vegas hotel rates change the further ahead you book?

Tags: hotels, las-vegas

Today I looked at room rates at the Mirage hotel in Las Vegas.

In June the rates were ~$25 more expensive than in late July.

I understand that July is a cheaper time in Vegas.

So is the change in price due to the season, or is it common place to get cheaper rates when you book further in the future in las Vegas?

EDIT: Also, today I July 13th, I checked the price of a flamingo basic fab room, and it is $249 for a Wednesday!! Compared to $64 for next Wednesday, and $59 for the one after that. Do Las Vegas hotel prices soar steeply in the few days leading up to that date?

Comment: It's not so much how far ahead you book as that you're going into what passes for an off-season in Las Vegas.

Comment: I have seen them become significantly cheaper (129->69, or 79->29 another time); I actually watch my bookings over the weeks, and sometimes rebook the same room cheaper when it becomes available (canceling the old own, _afterwards_ of course). That works only with cancellable rates of course, but you can sometimes do it the day of your arrival still... they play the games, so I can play them too.

Answer (score 10):

Having managed hotels for Hilton I can honestly tell you it varies depending on a number of factors including the room type (Kings, Doubles, Suites), day of the week, how booked the hotel is, as well as events that may or may not be going on. Hotels with good management will know in advance when all the big events are so they have the higher rates set over a year out, so it doesn't matter how early you try to book. Some hotels are better at keeping up with events than others. If you find a hotel that seems to be behind the curve with changing their rate levels in relation to events, look them up right away when you want to attend and the earlier the better. I know of some hotels (in other cities, not Vegas) who only update their rates a few weeks or so before a big event. The people who booked earlier, whether they are attending that event or not, get good deals.

Unless you are friendly with a desk clerk that can let you know how a certain hotel manages its rates and when the lower rates are, the online calendars are pretty good at being able to scan for lower prices. Most hotels have something like a "flexible dates" checkbox on their websites (I know Hilton and Marriott do) so you can find the lower rates if you have flexibility in your travel.

If you have already booked your flights and are pinned down to a certain date, then your options are reduced.

Comment: I just stumbled upon your answer and it is great to have your inside knowledge here, upvoted and welcome to Travel SE! Here is another question that you might be able to give a contribution to: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/62745/32134 - I currently have a bounty on it and would be happy to reward it to a good answer of yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Hotel room rates are now similar to airline ticket prices; they can change often depending on a variety of factors, besides time of year.  Other factors:

- Big boxing match in town
- Consumer Electronics Show (CES) the first week in January, or other big conventions
- Big-name concerts

So it is almost a roll of the dice (sorry) to get the best rate. If your plans are flexible, check different weekends, or different arrival/departure days. @Aganju comment to to book fully-refundable rates and keep checking is great idea too.