# Flight + hotel flexible dates search?

Tags: bookings, online-resources, hotels, flight-search-engines, accommodation-search-engines

Here on Travel.SE we have a well-developed question about how to search flights with flexible dates and destinations [How can I do a "broad" search for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights)
We also have some pieces how to find the hotel offerings flexibly 
[Hotel booking sites with a calendar view, similar to flight search engines?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49399/hotel-booking-sites-with-a-calendar-view-similar-to-flight-search-engines)
[How do I find the cheapest date to book a given hotel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62745/how-do-i-find-the-cheapest-date-to-book-a-given-hotel/71930)
though the use of the latter is very little as most solutions are outdated and don't exist anymore.

But I found little to none info about how to make combined search of the former and the latter.
What if I want to go to the Red Sea Coast but I'm pretty flexible about dates and the only thing I know is I want to visit it somewhere between November and December and stay in the first line hotel with a sea view.
Egypt is pretty famous for its package deals (flight + hotel all-inclusive), is there any search engine, app or aggregator that provides such deals overview in monthly calendar or I want too much?

**Note: I do not need Egypt-specific suggestions, I seek destination-agnostic comprehensive solution. Egypt is taken only as an example.**